# O que tem de errado no meu codigo css?

Tags: php, html, css

O que tem de errado no meu código css?

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tags são para identificar a pergunta, não seu projeto. Não importa se está usando PHP e HTML, se a pergunta é sobre CSS, basta somente essa tag.

Answer (score 2):

Há um erro de digitação.
"max-width" e não "max-widht"